# pygame click event at once

Tags: python, pygame

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        return False, "END"

    #  mouse button click
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print("clicked")
        # x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if obj["start"].rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            initialize()
            return True, "GAME"
        if obj["exit"].rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            return False, "END"
        if obj["tutorial"].rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            return False, "TUTORIAL"
```

When I click button 2~3 times, "clicked" printed at once. But when I click button first without any extra useless clicking(like clicking background), this code works properly.
My operating system is macOS and python version is 3.9.6.

I've tried to change event dectection if state to "if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:" and change MOUSEBUTTONDOWN to MOUSEBUTTONUP, but result was same.